Euler Lagrange equation with $f(x,y')$
The problem is to find the function $y(x)$ which makes the integral
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \sqrt{x} \sqrt{1+(y')^2}\, \mathrm dx$$  stationary. So if we use the Euler-Lagrange equation $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$, then this gives us a solution of the form $ y = 2k \sqrt{x-k^2} + c$.
However when we applied the Euler-Lagrange equation we assumed that our function $f$ was explicitly dependent on $y$ along with $x$ and $y'$. But if I assume $Y(x) = y(x) + \alpha \eta(x)$ and $f$ is a function of only $x$ and $y'$, then \begin{align*}
I &=  \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x,y') \, \mathrm dx\\
\implies \frac{\partial I}{\partial \alpha} &=  \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \alpha} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial Y'}\frac{\partial Y'}{\partial \alpha}\right)  \mathrm dx \\
&=  \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \left[0 +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial Y'} \eta '(x)\right] \mathrm dx = 0
\end{align*}
when the integral is stationary.
Since $\eta'(x)$ is arbitrary, this implies $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} = 0$.
This gives $y'(x) = 0$, so $y = c$, where $c$ is some constant. This solution is a subset of what we got by the Euler-Lagrange equation (i.e., if $k=0$).
So ideally shouldn't the Euler-Lagrange equation be inapplicable when our integrand is explicitly independent of $y$? I don't understand why we can apply the Euler Lagrange equation here and what is wrong in the process I did above.

You need to evaluate $\frac{\partial I}{\partial\alpha}$ at $\alpha = 0$ and integrate by parts before invoking the lemma about arbitrary functions.

Please fix the typo in the E-L equation.

A solution to Euler-Lagrange equation is not an admissible extremal yet - it must also satisfy boundary conditions. The way you treat $\eta'$ as arbitrary, one concludes that at least one end is open/free (no a priory condition on $y$ at $x=x_1$ or $x=x_2$ is imposed) - otherwise $\eta'$ is conditioned. In case, a boundary condition is missing, another condition - the natural boundary condition - is applied instead, which in this problem becomes $y'=0$ at the corresponding free end, giving immediately $k=0$, and, thus, $y=c$. Therefore, both solutions agree.

Yeah I understood it now. The criteria for the E-L equation to hold true is $ \eta(x1) =   \eta(x2) = 0 $ which is not valid for  $\eta'$. So $\eta'$  is actually not arbitrary in a sense and hence the last step is incorrect.  Thank you!

@Aspirant29 Right. If the problem has both ends fixed, then $\eta(x_1)=\eta(x_2)=0$ and $\eta'$ is not arbitrary (conditioned to $\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\eta'(x),dx=0$). If at least one boundary condition is missing then the variation with respect to this free end being zero is an additional requirement to be satisfied (so called "natural boundary condition") besides E-L equation.

Its the case of a nonuniform length x and translation invariant Lagrangian $L$, eg in a standard metric tangent space
$$L= \frac{1}{2} g(x) y'^2$$
$$\frac{d}{x} (g(x) y'(x) == g'(x) y'(x) + g(x) y''(x)=0$$
$$\frac{y''}{y'}\ = \  \log(y')' = -\log(g(x))' \quad y'= - g(x) + c\quad y= -\int g dx + cx + d.$$  The right side might be used to define uniform arc length.

Consider the problem:
Find the function $y(x)$ which makes the integral
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(y(x), x)\, \mathrm dx
$$
with $f(y,x) = \sqrt{x} \sqrt{1+y^2}$, stationary, subject to
$$y(x) = g(x)$$
The Lagrangian reads
$$
\mathscr{L}(y,\lambda,x) = f(y,x) +\lambda\left(y(x) - g(x)\right)
$$
and applying the Euler-Lagrange conditions, we have
$$
\cases{
\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial y}+\lambda = 0\\
y(x) = g(x)
}
$$
but in the case,
$$
g(x) = \int_{a}^{x} y(\eta)\mathrm d\eta
$$
if $y(x),g(x)$  have sufficient regularity, we can use instead
$$
y(x) = \dot y(x)
$$
and thus the Euler-Lagrange conditions are equivalent to
$$
\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial \dot y}+\lambda = 0
$$
Now as long as $\lambda$ is generic, choosing $\lambda = \lambda_0$ a non-null constant, we arrive at
$$
\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial \dot y}=-\lambda_0
$$
so in those circumstances, the problem: stationary solutions for
$$
\Big\{\int_a^b \mathscr{L}(\dot y, x)dx\Big\}\equiv \Big\{\int_a^b\mathscr{L}(y, x)dx \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ y = \int_a^x y(\eta)d\eta\Big\}
$$
with given $\{a,y(a), b,y(b)\}$, are equivalent.
